# Apache Directory Studio does not show Root DSE entries

Tags: browser, ldap, apache-directory

we have a problem with Apache Directory Studio (Version: 2.0.0.v20200411-M15 and previous).
When we connect to an OpenLDAP instance we can't see the naming contexts of the Root DSE.
We have the OpenLDAP configured as multi-master and the strange thing is that in one node we can see it and not in the other.
[Root DSE with missing entry screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxFPV.png)

[Root DSE showing the entry screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZYBo.png)

When we try to get the info via ldapsearch, we can see the correct naming context for both nodes:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://localhost:16389 -x -D "cn=adminLDAPI,ou=system,dc=XXXXXXX,dc=com" -W -s base -a always "(objectClass=*)" "namingcontexts"
```

[ldapsearch finds namingcontexts screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYWtp.png)

If we try to fetch the Base DNs with the connection options, it is not fetched on the "wrong" node.
[No base DN returned screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWBEn.png)
And neither entering manually works.

I've checked cn=config and cn=database but is all the same.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: usually when i connect successfully but cannot see any entries below the root DSE, it is due to an authentication/authorization issue. could it be that your credentials are only 'good' on one of the nodes?

Comment: Hi scottysseus, no, it's not a problem of credentials because they are in multi-master and with another LDAP Browser I can see the entries in both nodes.

Comment: How did you solve your issue? I am facing the same issue. Would be really helpful if you can just right a hint! here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/65748223/1833232

Comment: @MiguelSalinas can you please help out regarding the issue? how you have fixed that?