# Ldap Apache Directory Studio can not open Root DSE in osx big sur

Tags: eclipse, ldap, apache-directory

After upgrading my macOsx version to Big Sur(11.1) I am facing weird issue. When I connect the LDAP server I see all information except the DSE root tree not expanding and can not perform any operation for example search/filter. Here its looks like

[image: This is how it looks like for Root DSE]

I got the following **error message**:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException (Hexdump: 30 7E 02 01 06 65 07 0A 01 00 04 00 04 00 A0 70 30 6E 04 17 31 2E 33 2E 36 2E 31 2E 34 2E 31 2E 32 36 30 32 37 2E 31 2E 35 2E 34 01 01 FF 04 50 30 4E 04 4C 64 63 3D 70 6F 72 73 63 68 65 2C 64 63 3D 63 6F 6D 3A 30 30 30 30 30 31 37 37 30 61 38 33 62 33 63 37 37 64 32 62 30 30 61 38 30 31 61 61 20 30 30 30 30 30 31 37 37 30 61 38 33 65 33 65 61 37 62 65 30 30 30 61 30 61 36 62 31 3B)
```

With the following exception **stack trace**:

```
org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolDecoderException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Hexdump: 30 7E 02 01 06 65 07 0A 01 00 04 00 04 00 A0 70 30 6E 04 17 31 2E 33 2E 36 2E 31 2E 34 2E 31 2E 32 36 30 32 37 2E 31 2E 35 2E 34 01 01 FF 04 50 30 4E 04 4C 64 63 3D 70 6F 72 73 63 68 65 2C 64 63 3D 63 6F 6D 3A 30 30 30 30 30 31 37 37 30 61 38 33 62 33 63 37 37 64 32 62 30 30 61 38 30 31 61 61 20 30 30 30 30 30 31 37 37 30 61 38 33 65 33 65 61 37 62 65 30 30 30 61 30 61 36 62 31 3B)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:263)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:650)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1300(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1128)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslHandler.flushMessageReceived(SslHandler.java:330)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.ssl.SslFilter.messageReceived(SslFilter.java:552)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:650)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1300(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:1128)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.messageReceived(IoFilterAdapter.java:122)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:650)
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:643)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:539)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$1200(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:68)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1222)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1211)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:683)
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.directory.api.ldap.codec.actions.controls.StoreControlValue.action(StoreControlValue.java:81)
    at org.apache.directory.api.ldap.codec.actions.controls.StoreControlValue.action(StoreControlValue.java:49)
    at org.apache.directory.api.asn1.ber.grammar.AbstractGrammar.executeAction(AbstractGrammar.java:136)
    at org.apache.directory.api.asn1.ber.Asn1Decoder.treatTLVDoneState(Asn1Decoder.java:604)
    at org.apache.directory.api.asn1.ber.Asn1Decoder.decode(Asn1Decoder.java:740)
    at org.apache.directory.api.ldap.codec.protocol.mina.LdapProtocolDecoder.decode(LdapProtocolDecoder.java:137)
    at org.apache.directory.api.ldap.codec.protocol.mina.LdapProtocolDecoder.decode(LdapProtocolDecoder.java:86)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:254)
    ... 20 more
```

And here is my **session data** if you expert might thinks it could be helpful

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_271
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  /studio-rcp/resources/icons/linux/studio.xpm -keyring /Users/naimrajiv/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 /studio-rcp/resources/icons/linux/studio.xpm -keyring /Users/naimrajiv/.eclipse_keyring
```

I am stuck more than a day with this and not sure what to do! Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like exactly the same happened for this https://stackoverflow.com/q/63565323/1833232 but there is no answer yet :(

Answer (score 1):

I have upgraded the Apache Studio to version: Version: 2.0.0.v20210213-M16
and it is working just fine

Answer (score 0):

maybe you made the mistake just like me, I copied an old connection properties to make a new one, and the "Browse Options >> Base DN" part was still the old one. fix that "base dn" to the correct one will fix the problem

Comment: Maybe you can provide him more details in your answer with a list of options, the meaning of some of this option etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).